# Picker interfere with onTapGesture

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

I want to clarify I've searched for an answer but didn't find anything useful.
I've already posted this question, but I've modified it since I provided the code with an image instead of using text.

I have the following code:

```swift
struct TimeChoiceView: View {

    @State var buttonText = "None"
    @State var isPressed = false
    var text : String = "SomeView"

    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            HStack{
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20){
                    Text(text).padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 15, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)).font(.system(size: 14))
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack(alignment: .trailing){
                        Text(buttonText).padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 15)).foregroundColor(.gray).font(.system(size: 14)).onTapGesture {
                            self.isPressed = !self.isPressed
                            self.buttonText = self.buttonText == "None" ? "Undo" : "None"
                        }
                }
            }
            HStack {
                if isPressed {
                    TimeChoice()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In this view, `TimeChoice` is a Picker implemented with this code:

```swift
struct TimeChoice: View{
    @State var hours: Int = 8
    @State var minutes: Int = 30

    var body: some View {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Picker("", selection: $hours){
                        ForEach(0..<23, id: \.self) { i in
                            Text("\(i)").tag(i)
                        }
                    }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle()).frame(width: 50, height: 70).clipped()
                    Text(":")
                    Picker("", selection: $minutes){
                        ForEach(0..<60, id: \.self) { i in
                            Text(i < 10 ? "0\(i)" : "\(i)").tag(i)
                        }
                        }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle()).frame(width: 50, height: 70).clipped()
                    Spacer()
                }
    }
}
```

The appearence of the picker is triggered by `onTapGesture` method in `TimeChoiceView`, but as you can see, trying to pressing again on the `Undo` button does not trigger the related action. I can set the picker, but not the button. I have reason to think this is linked to `.onTapGesture` method interfering with the picker, since this only happens as soon as I press the button and the picker disappear. Has anyone experienced such behaviour?

Comment: Would you provide minimal reproducible example, because provided code is not testable due to absent dependencies?

Comment: @Asperi sorry, it should work now. I missed some fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in provided code `Picker` overlaps button when opened (even being visually clipped), so handle all tap events.

The solution is place button panel *above* optionally shown pickers view. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
var body: some View{
    VStack{
        HStack{
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20){
                Text(text).padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 15, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)).font(.system(size: 14))
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack(alignment: .trailing){
                    Text(buttonText).padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 15)).foregroundColor(.gray).font(.system(size: 14))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.isPressed.toggle()
                        self.buttonText = self.buttonText == "None" ? "Undo" : "None"
                    }
            }
        }.zIndex(1)          // << here !!
        HStack {
            if isPressed {
                TimeChoice()
            }
        }
    }
}
```